# Redirect all requests from port 80 to 443

Tags: linux, proxy, raspberry-pi, reverse-proxy

I have a vps setup with proxy configured to redirect to my home server via vpn.

How do I disable port 80 so when the user types in browser http://my.domain he will be redirected to https://my.domain ? Or how do I enable secure connection only ?

As an example look at http://vk.com - even when you open http link it creates secure https connection.

If I just keep <VirtualHost *:443> and remove <VirtualHost *:80> from /etc/apache2/sites-available/myconf.conf it shows default apache2 page when I open http://my.domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName my.domain
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```